# 00913. 00000 - "too many values" when trying to insert data to a nested table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO PatientTbl (sysID,id,name,dob,phone,hospVisits)
     VALUES (
             'P002',
             '491221019V',
             'Dulani Perera',
             '3-FEB-49',
             phone_arr_ty(0112233211),
             hospVisitsNt_ty_tbl(
                                 hospVisits_ty(
                                               75.00,
                                               '25-MAY-06',
                                               (SELECT REF(d)
                                                  FROM DoctorTbl d
                                                 WHERE d.regNo = 2342111322),
                                               550.00
                                              )
                                ),
             hospVisitsNt_ty_tbl(
                                 hospVisits_ty(
                                               90.00,
                                               '29-MAY-06',
                                               (SELECT REF(d)
                                                  FROM DoctorTbl d
                                                 WHERE d.regNo = 2344114344),
                                               300.00
                                              )
                                )
            );

/
```

As in the above query I'm trying to insert values to a nested table in ORDBMS.

[image]

So then above error is generated. How to insert data to a table which included nested table with multiple rows? Please help me to solve this problem as soon as possible

Comment: looks like you try to insert more values than table has rows. Format your sql. Read this https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00913.php

Comment: List your column names explicitly.

Comment: I have updated the answer as you mention. But still same error appears

Answer (score 0):

You try to insert two columns hospVisitsNt_ty_tbl...
The right insert is:

```
INSERT INTO PatientTbl (sysID,id,name,dob,phone,hospVisits)
 VALUES (
         'P002',
         '491221019V',
         'Dulani Perera',
         '3-FEB-49',
         phone_arr_ty(0112233211),
         hospVisitsNt_ty_tbl(
                             hospVisits_ty(
                                           75.00,
                                           '25-MAY-06',
                                           (SELECT REF(d)
                                              FROM DoctorTbl d
                                             WHERE d.regNo = 2342111322),
                                           550.00
                                          ),
                             hospVisits_ty(
                                           90.00,
                                           '29-MAY-06',
                                           (SELECT REF(d)
                                              FROM DoctorTbl d
                                             WHERE d.regNo = 2344114344),
                                           300.00
                                          )
                            )
        );
```